# React : How to pass an element in nested child component to nested parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have a component that one of it's props could receive an element (to focus/set any attr/ etc..). One of this component Children is an component which have a Button element(and will be available in DOM). How could I ref/pass this `<Button ../>` element to  `closeButtonContent` prop in `<Dialog .. />` parent component ?

On right: `<NewsletterWrapper />`
On left:  `<NewsletterConfirmed />`

[image: Dialog's prop "closeButtonContent" accepts an element which I would like to reference the Button element from nested NewsletterConfirmed component]

Comment: Add a code snippet instead of the image please

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a class or function to property, then in `Dialog`, after `children`, invoke the passed component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2xjm9z9n2r

Comment: Thanks, but its not the case here (no use for children in your code and I don't have control over Dialog component anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply pass a handler (that takes arguments about `<Button />` related stuff) as a prop from `<NewsletterConfirmed />` down to `<NewsletterWrapper />`, and call the handler from `<NewsLetterWrapper />` when needed. `ref`s are generally considered as anti-pattern in React.

```js
// in NewsLetterConfirmed
someHandler(buttonClassName) {
  // write your logic here
  if (buttonClassName === 'class1') {
    // ...
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <NewsLetterWrapper handleButtonEvent={this.someHandler.bind(this)} />
  )
}

// in NewsLetterWrapper


render() {
  // For example, what you care about is the button's class name
  return (
    <Button className={this.state.buttonClassName} onClick={() => this.props.handleButtonEvent(this.state.buttonClassName)}>Click Me!</Button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working. Dialog component's prop should accept the button element from its child component, className is not helping me here.

Comment: @toufekkhoury What is the attribute that you want to get from the button? Usually we don't need to actually to have the ref to the element. Also see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs